# groupRow attribute doesn't work correctly for some columns of p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, grouping

My `p:dataTable` has 3 columns:

```
                        <p:dataTable
                            id="producaoDataTable"
                            value="#{clienteMB.producaoList}"
                            var="producao">
                            <p:column
                                headerText="Especialidade"
                                groupRow="true">
                                <h:outputText value="#{producao.modalDesc()}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column
                                headerText="Dente"
                                groupRow="true">
                                <h:outputText value="#{producao.dente}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column
                                headerText="Procedimento"
                                groupRow="true">
                                <h:outputText value="#{producao.utDesc()}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

While `groupRow` works fine for the first `p:column`, that doesn't work for the second one and works partially for the third one:

[image]

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Might simply be that grouping within grouping does not work (was not implemented. What is your PF version? And please make an [mcve] so someone can easily try to reproduce

Comment: And btw, `#{producao.modalDesc()}` are 'strange' why not real getters/setters? Maybe the values that are returned now are not 'identical' and no grouping is done.

Comment: It might, but the documentation has nothing about that. And it's the last version, 6.1. And I think the code will attend your expectation now.

Comment: `#{producao.modalDesc()}` is not the problem. If I put that as the first column, the groupping works. And If I put the first column as the second one, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ok, good to know the `#{producao.modalDesc()}` is not the problem. Regarding the 'code will attend your expectation now'. I tried copy-pasting the xhtml you posted in a clean new fresh PrimeFaces project, but I get a lot of errors... Beans not found etc... Did you try this same action?

Comment: You don't need all my classes to simulate the problem, Kukeltje. You just need to create a simple bean and xhtml with a PrimeFaces datatable. It shouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: But I don't **want** to do that.  Suppose I make an accidental error and I'm chasing that one. Or that I by accident don't make an error that you did make, then I cannot reproduce. Both cost me time in helping you solve your problem that I (or others) cannot spend in finding the real cause (which I still think is: "just not supported")

Comment: Tried having some differences in the values in the second column? Now all are the same for the whole group (it makes a difference, I found out!

Comment: Actually there are two different values on the second column. Anyway, thanks for trying to help me with that.It seems to be a bug in PrimeFaces and I will look for an alternative to that.

Comment: All the values in the second colomn **within** the first grouped column are identical. Try changing that as a test. All the effective row grouping is done on the client-side (to my surprise). so it is easily overridable. The PrimeFaces source **IS** open...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155442/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-marcel-jacques-machado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly fixed in version 6.1.1:

[Datatable Column groupRow Row Spans Incorrect Column If More Than One Column Marked as Grouped #2210](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2210)

Unfortunately, that's not available for the community. The same fix will be in the upcoming 6.2 release.

Comment: So next time you first search the issuelist and/or try the code from trunk and if that all still fails, post a question with version info, what you tried and a [mcve]?

Comment: As long as questions are 'bad', I'll keep doing this.. **there is a reason it it is requested in SO, a reason you as a wannabe developer obviously do not see yet and since you did not really tried to help others yet (why not?) you also fail to see the reason from that side . But, no problem, I'll ignore all your Q's... Good luck