# How to access enum methods when using p:importEnum component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, enums

I'm using this code on my xhtml:

```
<p:importEnum
    type="com.test.ProcedimentoMetaEnum"
    var="ProcedimentoMetaEnum"
    allSuffix="ALL_ENUM_VALUES" />
```

I have no problem to access the enum values. This works fine:

```
#{ProcedimentoMetaEnum.PUP.codigo}
```

But I can't access the methods. This doesn't work:

```
#{ProcedimentoMetaEnum.test()}
```

> Error: "Unable to find method [test] with [0] parameters"

```
public static void test() {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

The documentation has no much information about `importEnum`. It just says:

> It also possible to get all enum values of the class with the
>   "ALL_VALUES" suffix or a custom prefix via the "allSuffix" attribute.

So I would like to call the enum methods. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why would you call a method on an enum directly? And I think it is just not supposed to work (it feels 'wrong' to call the methods directly and not via a controller...)

Comment: It's funny you edit and comment ALL my questions about Primefaces, but you never have an answer to help me...

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado i have reproduced your code and runs well, how are you calling the method? what is the PF version?

Comment: That is because all your questions are sort of wrong. Tagging a question with java(se) means you can reproduce the issue in a plain jsdk with a simple class with a main and you think it is a plain jdk issue. You cannot in this case since you **need** jsf. So people reading/answering Java these java questions see your not related ones... waste of their time.

Comment: And I DID suggest that I'd think it is not supported and I did not try to reproduce since version info is missing and it is not an [mcve] and not in line with [ask] (see e.g. @C.P.O **asking** for more info which should be provided upfront). If I'd need to correct all that on my side just to try **for every wrong question, not only yours**, I'd need 48 hours in a day.

Comment: And I did try to help e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46435651/grouprow-attribute-doesnt-work-correctly-for-some-columns-of-pdatatable even with lots of comments in a chat and even stating that it worked in the showcase (and no version info from you there initially and no [mcve].  so PLEASE don't state that I'm not helping.